# Efficiently reshuffle and combine 16 3-bit numbers in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I have an array of sixteen unsigned numbers, where each number is less than 8 (e.g. it can be represented by 3 bits). These sixteen numbers are loaded in a `uint8x16_t` q-register. I need to reshuffle and combine them, similarly to this pseudo-code:

```
void reshuffleCombine(uint8_t src[16], uint64_t* dst)
{
    uint64 d = 0;

    d |= uint64(src[0])  << 45;
    d |= uint64(src[4])  << 42;
    d |= uint64(src[8])  << 39;
    d |= uint64(src[12]) << 36;

    d |= uint64(src[1])  << 33;
    d |= uint64(src[5])  << 30;
    d |= uint64(src[9])  << 27;
    d |= uint64(src[13]) << 24;

    d |= uint64(src[2])  << 21;
    d |= uint64(src[6])  << 18;
    d |= uint64(src[10]) << 15;
    d |= uint64(src[14]) << 12;

    d |= uint64(src[3])  << 9;
    d |= uint64(src[7])  << 6;
    d |= uint64(src[11]) << 3;
    d |= uint64(src[15]) << 0;

    *dst = d;
}

void reshuffleCombineNeon(uint8x16_t src, uint64_t* dst)
{
    uint64x1_t res;
    // ??
    vst1_u64(dst, res);
}
```

I can reshuffle them with 1 vld followed by 1 vtbl, however, this entire operation is one of final steps and isn't repeated many times (e.g. 1 vld cannot be shared between multiple reshuffleCombines), thus it might be better to use vtrn/vzip if that's possible and could be more efficient than vld+vtbl. However, the main point of the question: how can I merge all these sixteen 3-bit numbers into a single 48-bit value (stored in a 64-bit uint). This function runs at the end of algorithm, the 16 3-bit numbers come from neon and result of the functions is stored in memory.

[My neon version](https://godbolt.org/g/cp43CD):

```
void reshuffleCombineNeon(uint8x16_t src, uint32_t* dst)
{
    static const uint8_t idx0[] = { 15, 7, 14, 6, 13, 5, 12, 4 };
    static const uint8_t idx1[] = { 11, 3, 10, 2, 9,  1, 8,  0 };

    uint8x8x2_t y;
    y.val[0] = vget_low_u8(src);
    y.val[1] = vget_high_u8(src);

    uint8x8_t vidx0 = vld1_u8(idx0);
    uint8x8_t vidx1 = vld1_u8(idx1);
    uint8x8_t x0 = vtbl2_u8(y, vidx0);
    uint8x8_t x1 = vtbl2_u8(y, vidx1);

    uint8x8_t x01 = vsli_n_u8(x0, x1, 3);
    uint16x8_t x01L = vmovl_u8(x01);

    uint32x4_t x01LL = vsraq_n_u32(vreinterpretq_u32_u16(x01L), vreinterpretq_u32_u16(x01L), 10);
    x01LL = vmovl_u16(vmovn_u32(x01LL));

    uint64x2_t x01X = vsraq_n_u64(vreinterpretq_u64_u32(x01LL), vreinterpretq_u64_u32(x01LL), 20);
    x01X = vmovl_u32(vmovn_u64(x01X));

    uint64x1_t X0 = vget_low_u64(x01X);
    uint64x1_t X1 = vget_high_u64(x01X);
    X0 = vsli_n_u64(X0, X1, 24);
    vst1_u32(dst, vreinterpret_u32_u64(X0));
}
```

Comment: What's the point? Stick to your C version for anything less than 128 bytes total. That's the rule of thumb.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE My measurements show that my neon attempt on this functions do not provide much benefit, but I still do see it. Even though it's a leaf function of the algorithm, the algorithm is called tens of thousands of times per few milliseconds. So, if I can save 10-20 cycles on it I'll have sensible impact on overall runtime. Basically these 16 3-bit numbers come from neon and result of this function goes to memory. If I do it all in neon I avoid stall and possibly can do better in neon than in arm itself.

Comment: Only because you are running it on an ooo machine. It would be much slower than plain C version on in-order ones. And unless the performance is crucial, you shouldn't use NEON at all if the performance gain is less than 100% because of the steep increase in power consumption.

Comment: I run my algorithm in a loop 10K times, so this particular piece runs around 500K times. I profile for overall time and I do get improvements, but because of ooo and because this piece is small it's difficult to see details of how much better it is. I do suspect however, that my neon version isn't that good ;)

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I added my neon version. It's clearly shorter than c version and avoid storing 16 bytes and reading them.

Comment: You should know that pretty much every NEON instruction comes with a latency of 3~6 cycles with integer operations while there is none for most ALU instructions on ARM. The NEON version might be shorter when properly written, but the latencies hit hard on in-order machines.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Neon latency and buffered execution (neon opcodes go to their own execution queue) makes it difficult to profile neon. `pc` increases but doesn't really indicate what neon instruction currently executes. I can only tell if overall time gets better and I can see some profiler measurements that clearly show neon stalls.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE regarding `Stick to your C version for anything less than 128 bytes total` - I could possibly defer this last step and process these intermediate results at the end. This will make it loop over this function more than 50K times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for whatever it's worth, below is a NEON version optimized to my best knowledge:

---

```
rev64   v16.16b, v16.16b
usra    v16.2d, v16.2d, #32-3       // 8 elements (8bit)
ushll   v17.8h, v16.8b, #6
uaddw2  v16.8h, v17.8h, v16.16b     // 4 elements (16bit)
uxtl    v16.4s, v16.4h
usra    v16.2d, v16.2d, #32-12      // 2 elements (32bit)
ushll2  v17.2d, v16.4s, #24
uaddw   v16.2d, v17.2d, v16.2s      // 1 element (64bit), d16 contains the result
```

---

It should be considerably faster than yours, but again, it won't make much sense on in-order machines.

Comment: I'm right now refactoring/rewriting my code and and the first two opcodes are exactly what I have